# Python Google BigQuery, how to authenticate without JSON file?

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I have a JSON file with BigQuery credentials. To connect with Python to BigQuery I need to give the file path in service_account.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename="credentials.json")
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=cred, project=cred.project_id)
```

The JSON looks like a dictionary:

```
{
  "type": "xxxx",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "xxxxxx",
  "client_email": "xxxx@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "xxxxxx",
  "token_uri": "xxxxxx",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "xxxxx",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I don't want to use a file in the project. Is there a way instead of a path to file to use JSON string from the dictionary to connect to BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the constructor `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(sa_dict)` instead.

[Docs](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info)

be careful if you upload the code to a public repo though. One of the reasons to use a separate JSON file is so you can exclude it from repos.

```py
sa_dict = {
  "type": "xxxx",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "xxxxxx",
  "client_email": "xxxx@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "xxxxxx",
  "token_uri": "xxxxxx",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "xxxxx",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(sa_dict)
```